# React Native error, Redux: The slice reducer for key "nav" returned undefined during initialization

Tags: react-native, react-redux, metro-bundler

Making an uber clone with React Native, while setting up the Redux while making the app in the first place, the Metro bundler returned these errors:

```
Error: The slice reducer for key "nav" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
......

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
    * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
    * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

.....
```

This is the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store';

// 1. Set up redux - done
// 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Uber</Text>
    </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is the navSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const innitialState = {
    origin: null,
    destination: null,
    travelTimeInformation: null,
}

export const navSlice = createSlice({
    name:"nav",
    innitialState,
    reducer: {
        setOrigin: (state, action) =>{
            state.origin = action.payload;
        },
        setDestination: (state, action) =>{
            state.destination = action.payload;
        },
        setTravelTimeInformation: (state, action) =>{
            state.travelTimeInformation = action.payload;
        },
        
    }
});

export const { setOrigin, setDestination, setTravelTimeInformation } = navSlice.actions;

// Selectors

export const selectOrigin = (state) => state.nav.origin;
export const selectDestination = (state) => state.nav.destination;
export const selectTravelTimeInformation = (state) => state.nav.travelTimeInformation;

export default navReducer = navSlice.reducer;
```

This is the Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import navReducer from "./slices/navSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        nav: navReducer,
    },
});
```

What are the reasons I am getting back these errors?
How can I fix this?
Is there an issue with how I am setting up the redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your innitialState spelling is wrong.
Change it to initialState

Answer (score 2):

Change the spelling in navslice to reducers and restart emulator